# Rails Application on Nginx and Thin, 400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large

Tags: nginx

Static page is served correctly you can visit : http://www.ec2.lankenow.info/
click on the image and it will take you to the error page.

Nginx error log:

```
2012/03/16 01:58:41 [alert] 884#0: 768 worker_connections are not enough  

2012/03/16 01:58:41 [error] 887#0: *3900 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 23.21.141.105, server: www.ec2.lankenow.info, request: "GET /leads HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://23.21.141.105:80/leads", host: "www.ec2.lankenow.info", referrer: "http://www.ec2.lankenow.info/"
```

I think I might have to set client_header_buffer_size but dont know how or which file to edit.
Any direction how to go about it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: This can be added to the http section of nginx.conf which can be found in /etc/nginx/
or usr/local/nginx/ depending on your installation**

Config file under /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
upstream vdiamond {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000;
    server 0.0.0.0:3001;
    server 0.0.0.0:3002;        
}


server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.ec2.lankenow.info;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/vdiamond/log/access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/vdiamond/log/error.log;

    root   /home/ubuntu/vdiamond/public/;
    index  index.html;

    location / {

        # Add expires header for static content
        location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
            if (-f $request_filename) {
                expires      max;
                break;
            }
        }

        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_next_upstream off;

        #proxy_redirect false;

        if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
            rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
        }

        if (-f $request_filename.html) {
            rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
        }

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://www.ec2.lankenow.info;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that the `worker_connections` is more likely the issue -- or, rather, the symptom -- why so many workers? Are there mistakes in your application that keep workers from being reaped or that too-easily spawns new workers?

Comment: Sorry, its not my app but managing someone else app code. I am just trying to set up test server so eventually I can fix the app.

Comment: Have you tried increasing worker_connections and workers?

Comment: try changing the configuration proxy_buffer_size -> http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffer_size or large_client_header_buffers -> http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#large_client_header_buffers

Comment: @sunny31 If you solved your problem, you should move the solution to an answer.  It makes it easier for future visitors with the same problem to understand what happened here.

Comment: Possibly related: [400 bad request request header or cookie too large nginx Rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17524396/425313)