# Nginx php error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I installed the nginx+php+mysql and my phpmyadmin working fine.

I downloaded wordpress and then I tried to run it and got the error:

```
015/02/04 22:47:06 [error] 21781#0: *45 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /smarter/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

I googled and tried everything to change in php5-fpm.sock listen.mode, group, owner everything but still not working.

Please help me to how to solve this critical problem.

Comment: What versions of PHP, nginx, and mysql are you using? You can find all of these in your phpinfo.

Comment: Do you get a bad gateway error when accessing the site? I ran into a problem that maybe it is related with a website of mine. The issue was that the Cookie that my php script set was quite big size. Maybe this question can point you to the right place http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524396/400-bad-request-request-header-or-cookie-too-large

Comment: i am using the PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Comment: this is already answer in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844761/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed something regarding the buffer size on your nginx configuration?

A kind of "dirty" solution would be to increase the buffer size like (but that may be more an workaround like an real solution). The values are examples.

```
 http {
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

Comment: I didn't made any changes like this

Comment: Hi
where should i keep these params

Comment: You may add them for testing to the nginx.conf-File. There should be an `http` section.