# Firefox upload file bigger than 10k: response HTTP 400

Tags: javascript, firefox, nginx, file-upload

This only happened in FF, not in Chrome or other browsers. I got the log  below:

[image: nginx log]

> [error] ... *2 part header is too long, client: ...

But I can upload images and other resources smaller than 10k, it's very strange.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Could you add the text of nginx's log to the question. This will prevent issues when/if imgur is down.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that cookies are included in the headers. Do you get the same result if you clear private data in Firefox?

If you know that the files you want to receive will be larger than 10k, try [increasing the allowed header size in the Nginx config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285146/2617885).

Comment: Yes, I cleaned FF cookie and all private data, but it didn't help for this.I'm confused why it didn't happay in other broswer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by add `Accept` into header as below:

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept'， '*/*');
```

I fought chrome set header `accept */*` and ff don't do like this.